# A union of subspaces $V_i...V_n$ is a subspace if and only if some $V_i$ contains all the others

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that this is true for $W_1, W_2$ subspaces of a vector space $V$, and $W_1 \cup W_2$ is a subspace if and only if $W_1\subset W_2$ or $W_2\subset W_1$.

But I am not sure how to prove this for the general case $n$ many subspaces of $V$ over $F$, where no assumptions are made on whether $F$ is an infinite or finite field.

Comment: Every vector space is a union of its one-dimensional subspaces. In the case of a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ a finite field, this is a finite union, so...

Comment: The first statement fails on spaces over finite fields. In particular, take a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for the counterexample, that is clear to me now. Can you outline the proof if F is infinite?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein what if $F$ is infinite? I know the proof for two subspaces, but I don't know how to write it for many subspaces...

Comment: See the solution to Problem 7 here: http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/math113/hw1.pdf

Comment: @GrayQuant take a look at the solution in Martin's link. Do you understand It?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are incorrect; the first statement holds for arbitrary vector spaces, regardless of the field. In fact, for any group $G$, abelian or otherwise (such as the underlying abelian group of a vector space), and subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$, it is true that $H \cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H \subset K$ or $K \subset H$.

Comment: @DustanL you're right. I suppose it's the union of $3$ that my example applied to

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I follow the proof but I am not sure it answers my question, did it prove the contrapositive to my statement?

Comment: Yes: it proves that if one space does not contain the others, then the union of subspaces cannot be a subspace.